# Is post-order traversal possible on a binary tree that is not arranged (sorted) like the one in this question?

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

Referring to the following question:

The answer suggests that post-order traversal is not possible. Is this correct?

I am struggling to understand whether the tree needs to be sorted (like would be the case when doing a binary search) in order for traversals to work. Could anyone point out the correct answer, and if this is incorrect, with an explanation.

From my understanding, if the question was changed to: In this "Binary Search Tree", that would not make sense, as a BST must be sorted. But is this also the case for an ordinary Binary tree?

I thought the answer, if it is not a binary search tree, should be:  d e b f g c a

Is that correct? If the question did state "Binary Search Tree", what would be an appropriate answer?

[image]

Comment: If the site says the correct answer is "a post-order traversal cannot be done", then the site is wrong. Your answer is correct. If the site claimed this to be a binary search tree, the site would be even more wrong.

Comment: Thank you - if it was a BST?